# How to make a while in a stored procedure with phpmyadmin, error #1064

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, while-loop, phpmyadmin

I try to create a stored procedure in phpmyadmin, but I get a error 1064 on line 12 (where the WHILE is). This is the first time I try to create a stored procedure.

```
BEGIN

DECLARE product_id INT;
DECLARE  product_min_age nvarchar(500);
DECLARE  cur CURSOR for
SELECT product_min_age, product_id FROM _vm_product;

open cur;

fetch next from cur into product_min_age, product_id;

while FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

    INSERT INTO _virtuemart_product_customfields (virtuemart_product_id, virtuemart_custom_id, customfield_value, customfield_params) VALUES
    ( product_id, 5, product_min_age, 'addEmpty=0|selectType=0|');

    fetch next from cur into product_min_age,product_id;
END;

close cur;

END
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change that to below. See [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html) for more information.

```
open cur;

read_loop: LOOP
fetch cur into product_min_age, product_id;

    INSERT INTO _virtuemart_product_customfields (virtuemart_product_id, virtuemart_custom_id, customfield_value, customfield_params) VALUES
    ( product_id, 5, product_min_age, 'addEmpty=0|selectType=0|');

END LOOP;

close cur;
```

Comment: @Rahul thank you, I also have a other question. Why there is a error when I try to name my variable with a @ in front. I saw a lot people doing it, but for me, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is indeed correct and so is your own answer. Unfortunately the approach is completely wrong!

One does not generally perform sql queries inside a loop unless as a last resort. Select / loop / insert is in fact a frequent pattern followed by people writing their first stored procedure. but there is a better way, a much much better way. And that is [INSERT .. SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html)

> With INSERT ... SELECT, you can quickly insert many rows into a table
>   from one or many tables. For example:

Your complex stored procedure reduces to:

```
INSERT INTO _virtuemart_product_customfields (virtuemart_product_id, virtuemart_custom_id, customfield_value, customfield_params) 
SELECT product_id, 5, product_min_age, 'addEmpty=0|selectType=0|' 
FROM _vm_product
```

That's it, just a simple select, no stored procedures!

A second issue is that you are stored delimited text in a column.

```
  addEmpty=0|selectType=0|
```

I am not quite sure why you are doing this but it's most unusual.

Comment: "addEmpty=0|selectType=0|" : I needed to do this, because I updated virtumart (A joomla component for e-commerce). I needed to take the old structure with thousand products to transform it into the new structure. I don't know why either, but "addEmpty=0|selectType=0|" is the value that is generate by default by this component.

Comment: glad to have been of use

Answer (score 0):

If someone want to see my final result:

```
BEGIN

DECLARE _product_id INT;
DECLARE  _product_min_age nvarchar(500);
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE  cur CURSOR for SELECT product_min_age, product_id FROM _vm_product;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

open cur;
read_loop: LOOP
fetch cur into _product_min_age, _product_id;
    IF done = 1 THEN
        LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO _virtuemart_product_customfields (virtuemart_product_id, virtuemart_custom_id, customfield_value, customfield_params) VALUES
    ( _product_id, 5, _product_min_age, 'addEmpty=0|selectType=0|');

END LOOP;

close cur;

END
```